# python create class with brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python I can create class as follows:

```py
class Car:

    def __init__(self):
       pass
```

But I have seen some people create class with empty brackets e.g.:

```py
class Car():

    def __init__(self):
       pass
```

The second form works, so my question is which one is the correct (or pythonic) way of defining class. I know that in brackets I can provide another class for inheritance e.g. `class Car(Vehicle):`, so when a class is created with empty brackets does it explicitly imply no inheritance?

Comment: Both are identical

Comment: The brackets are used for inheritance. If you don't want your class to inherit any class you can just leave them out

Answer (score 1):

In `python3`, you can just ignore the brackets.

In other words, `class Car` is equivalent to `class Car()` and the former one is more **pythonic**. However, In `python2`, you have to use `class Car(object)` to suit `python2`'s requirement.